# Table of content in Beamer without slide numbering

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, beamer

I'm trying to do the following:

- use the `metropolis` theme when exporting my Orgmode buffer to Beamer with slides numbering,
- have a table of contents with the numbering of the sections and without the numbering of the slides,
- have a slide showing the current section in the table of content at the beginning of each new section.

I'm almost there but I can't find a way to remove the slide numbering in the table of contents: I've circled that in red in the image below.

Here's a minimal example:

```
#+TITLE: Some title
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+OPTIONS: H:2 num:t toc:t author:nil
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usetheme[progressbar=foot, sectionpage=none, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamercovered{transparent=10}
# Show section number in the table of contents
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
# Show table of content between each section, do not increment the frame numbering and do not show the footer
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \AtBeginSection[] {  \begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]{Outline}    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]    \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]    \tableofcontents[currentsection, currentsubsection]  \end{frame}} \AtBeginSubsection[] {  \begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]{Outline}    \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]    \setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]  \end{frame}}
* Title 1
** Section 1
** Section 2
* Title 2
** Section A
** Section B
```

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: This is for the numbering of the titles in the table of content itself, I'd like to keep those numbered! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add

```
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
```

to your preamble to automatically suppress the footline on the outline frame.

---

To make it look as if the outline frame would not increase the framenumber, you could add

```
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
```

to your preamble.

---

And this is how it would look in the Org mode file:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly for the slide numbering!
But then I have a difference in items spacing between the first table of contents, and the table of contents showing only the current section. I thought it was cause by the slide numbering but maybe there's something else. Should this be another question?

Comment: @kir0ul Can you show the intermedia .tex file?

Comment: Probably a different question: that will allow you to point out exactly the difference in the spacing.

Comment: But since this answer answered your original question, you should [accept it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).