# Different spacing in table of contents in Org-Mode Beamer export

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, beamer

This is a follow-up of: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73564/2247.

In Org-Mode, I use the following code in Beamer export to create 1) a table of content, and 2) intermediate tables of contents between each section highlighting the current section:

```
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \hypersetup{pdfauthor={}}
#+TITLE: My awesome title
#+date: February 27^{th}, 2023
#+startup: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [bigger]
#+OPTIONS: H:2 num:t toc:t author:nil
#+LATEX_COMPILER: lualatex
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usetheme[progressbar=foot, sectionpage=none, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamercovered{transparent=10}

# Show section number in the table of contents
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]

# Show table of content between each section, do not increment the frame numbering and do not show the footer
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]{Outline}\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]\tableofcontents[currentsection, currentsubsection]\end{frame}}
#+BEAMER_HEADER: \AtBeginSubsection[]{\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]{Outline}\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]\end{frame}}

# Table of content without slide numbering
# https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/73562/2247
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}

  #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :results output :exports results :eval yes
    (customize-set-value 'org-latex-with-hyperref nil)
  #+END_SRC
* Section 1
** Subsection 1.1
** Subsection 1.2
* Section 2
** Subsection 2.1
** Subsection 2.2
```

This works great, but the issue is that the second table of content is shifted with respect to the first one, as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

Any idea how I could put both tables of contents at the same level?

Here's the TeX file produced by Org-Mode if that helps:

```tex
% Created 2023-02-27 Mon 16:21
% Intended LaTeX compiler: lualatex
\documentclass[bigger]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor={}}
\usetheme[progressbar=foot, sectionpage=none, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}
\pretocmd{\tableofcontents}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
\usetheme{default}
\date{February 27\textsuperscript{th}, 2023}
\title{My awesome title}
\setbeamercovered{transparent=10}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\AtBeginSection[]{\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]{Outline}\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]\tableofcontents[currentsection, currentsubsection]\end{frame}}
\AtBeginSubsection[]{\begin{frame}[plain, noframenumbering]{Outline}\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]\tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]\end{frame}}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{frame}{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}


\section{Section 1}
\label{sec:org99eee65}
\begin{frame}[label={sec:org2ea7719}]{Subsection 1.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label={sec:orgdb266d7}]{Subsection 1.2}
\end{frame}
\section{Section 2}
\label{sec:orgd93f92b}
\begin{frame}[label={sec:org05cbbd6}]{Subsection 2.1}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[label={sec:orgb32272e}]{Subsection 2.2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the TeXnical perspective you can avoid the problem by using `\begin{frame}[plain]{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}`

Comment: ... alternatively you could remove `plain` from your section tocs and also use `\thispagestyle{empty}` there...

Comment: Is this an Emacs question? Beamer question? LaTeX question?

Comment: It's kind of in the middle between LaTeX/Beamer and Org-Mode. Indeed, what @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggested solves the Beamer/LaTeX side, then there's also how you make it work from Org-Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz suggestion, let's add a `plain` option to the main outline frame. You can do that by customizing the variable `org-beamer-outline-frame-options` or by adding a file-local variable to your file:

```el
* COMMENT File-local variables
% Local variables:
% org-beamer-outline-frame-options: "plain"
% End:
```

We add it in a `COMMENT` section that will disappear on export, but Emacs will see it when it opens the file and it will set `org-beamer-outline-frame-options` appropriately. You will be asked whether to accept the setting of the variable: you can either say `y` or `!` - the `!` answer will remember that you have said that it's OK to accept the local variable setting in the future. You can learn more about [file-local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html) in the Emacs manual. Note that you have to close and reopen the file, or restart Emacs, or reinitialize the mode with `M-x normal-mode` in order for Emacs to see the changed value of the variable.

Or you can customize the variable once and for all.

Either way, the frame gets a `[plain]` option and there is no jumping up/down  when you go from the global outline to the section (or subsection) outlines.

Comment: This works perfectly! Just a quick comment for anyone like me who's not familiar with `file-local variables`: it took me a while to understand I had to reload the Org-Mode buffer to get the prompt asking to accept the setting of the variable.

Comment: There was a hint in "... Emacs will see it when it opens the file..." but I should have made it more explicit. I'll add a note.